# Docusign status and Docusign recipient status in salesforce doesn't gets record when we send doc to the user

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have integrated Conga with Docusign in Salesforce. I ran the process of generating and sending the document to the user for signing. This has worked very well without using the background mode Conga parameter(&DS7=17) with docusign status updated in salesforce(with signed date and time) but, when I use background mode enabled, docusign status of that object(Contact or Opportunity) in salesforce doesn’t gets updated(no record gets added).I'm very much new to all these tools. Sorry, if i'm asking a silly question over here. Button url used:

```
https://composer.congamerge.com
?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}
&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_290}
&id={!Contact.Id}

&TemplateId=a3X6F000000R4ue
&DocuSignVisible=1
&DocuSignR1ID={!Contact.Id}
&DocuSignR1Type=Signer
&DocuSignR1Role=Signer+1
&DocuSignEndpoint=demo
&DS7=17
```

Answer (score 0):

Sign into DocuSign admin
Click connect
Click salesforce
Scroll to the connected objects section
Edit dsfs_DocuSign_status
Add a new field
If it is the Account object use the Account reference Id and map it to the Envelope External Source Id

Try that the rest of the settings are located there. It took me forever to figure it out too!

Here is my example of setting it up to the Order object
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7M96.png)